# How to run a kind of code like python main.py in terminal?

Tags: python, bash, github, terminal, google-colaboratory

I used github and copied it by git clone.
https://github.com/Zeleni9/pytorch-wgan

but when I run the code：

```
python main.py --model WGAN-GP \
               --is_train True \
               --download True \
               --dataroot datasets/cifar \
               --dataset cifar \
               --generator_iters 40000 \
               --cuda True \
               --batch_size 64
```

```
RuntimeError: Unexpected error from cudaGetDeviceCount(). 
Did you run some cuda functions before calling NumCudaDevices() 
that might have already set an error? Error 2: out of memory
```

but I can run it on colab without any issue.
my terminal can use more GPU than colab. I guess the input code may have some problems?
Thank you in adcance.

Answer (score 1):

commands: 1.: chmod 770 main.py 2.: which python
(here you will know which python you have (for example: python3, and it's recommended) 3.: python3 main.py (should work)`